# DependencyProperty binding error, programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, user-controls

What I have is a well-working C# and XAML code, which does exactly what it is supposed to do, well, almost exactly. I am trying to make my custom, working, `DependencyProperty` for `UserControl` - and it is made, well-formed and supposedly working. There are two properties: `SumOfApproximationsProperty` and `SumOfPositionsProperty`. These getters and setters simply do not get invoked on certain actions - and this is my problem. They are declared in this `UserControl` class:

```
public partial class PresentationCell : UserControl
{
    public Label SumOfApproximations;
    public Label SumOfPositions;
    public PresentationCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.MinHeight = 40;
        this.MinWidth = 40;
        SumOfApproximations = this.SumOfApproximation;
        SumOfPositions = this.SumOfPosition;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SumOfApproximationsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AproximationsProperty", typeof(String),
    typeof(PresentationCell), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SumOfPositionsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PositionsProperty", typeof(String),
    typeof(PresentationCell), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public String AproximationsProperty
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SumOfApproximationsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SumOfApproximationsProperty, value); }
    }

    public String PositionsProperty
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SumOfPositionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SumOfPositionsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

As You can see, it is composed of two `Labels`, that have their own text-setting properties. And here's this `UserControl` XAML:

```
// USER CONTROL XAML
<UserControl x:Class="PodstawyModelowaniaISymulacjiRozmytej.Controls.PresentationCell"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*">
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*">
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Label Name="SumOfApproximation" Content="{Binding Path=AproximationsProperty}">
                </Label>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*">
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*">
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">

            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Label  Name="SumOfPosition"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This `UserControl` is going to be used with `DataGrid` (as it's cells), which is declared below (in XAML):

```
// MAIN WINDOW DATAGRIG DECLARATION MAINWINDOW.XAML
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="DataThree_Grid">
    <DataGrid Name="ResultData_DataGrid" HeadersVisibility="Row" Margin="5 5 5 5"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here's the code, that prepares and creates a column in this `DataGrid`, filled with `PresentationCell UserControls`:

```
// MAIN WINDOW CREATE COLUMN FOR DATAGRID FUNCTION MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS
private DataGridTemplateColumn CreatePresentationTemplateColumn(Binding positions, Binding aproximations)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn doubleOnlyTextBoxColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(PresentationCell));
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

    factory.SetValue(PresentationCell.SumOfApproximationsProperty, aproximations);
    factory.SetValue(PresentationCell.SumOfPositionsProperty, positions);
    dataTemplate.VisualTree = factory;
    doubleOnlyTextBoxColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
    return doubleOnlyTextBoxColumn;
}
```

Other code, that can be deemed useful for You to answer this question:

```
// MAIN WINDOW INITIALIZING BUTTON MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS
private void SubtractionLR_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyData[]  table = new MyData[] 
    { 
        new MyData 
        { 
            Values = new element[2] 
            { 
                new element 
                { 
                    var1 = 7, 
                    var2 = 6 
                }, 
                new element 
                { 
                    var1 = 4, 
                    var2 = 1 
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        new MyData 
        { 
            Values = new element[2]
            { 
                new element 
                { 
                    var1 = 67, 
                    var2 = 3 
                }, 
                new element 
                { 
                    var1 = 44, 
                    var2 = 1 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    };
    fillPresentationDataGrid(ResultData_DataGrid, table);
}
```

Now, after all of the code has been described, the problem lingers here. As You can see, I am trying to create Binding object for my column of `PresentationCell UserControls`. The problem is, that this String in this Binding is rather unknown for me - its specification and so on. As a result, program cannot find data that should be provided to my control (and for its labels) through this binding. The data should come from `MyData[] table`. Program shows an error about "cannot find Values" etc. and the cells in `DataGrid` are blank.

```
// MAIN WINDOW FILLING PRESENTATION GRID FUNCTION MAINWINDOW.XAML.CS
private void fillPresentationDataGrid(DataGrid dataGrid, MyData[] table)
{
    dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < table[0].Values.Length; i++)
    {

        DataGridTemplateColumn col = CreatePresentationTemplateColumn(new Binding("Values[" + i + "].var1"), new Binding("Values[" + i + "].var2"));
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    }
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = table;
}
```

---

EDIT

All I want is to get that `MyData[] table` content displayed on `DataGrid` control using my own custom `UserControl`. When I change that `factory.SetValue(PresentationCell.SumOfApproximationsProperty, aproximations);` into `factory.SetValue(PresentationCell.SumOfApproximationsProperty, "foo");`, the `DataGrid` will display "foo"'s.

---

EDIT2

Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: Dependency property wrappers never gets called when changed from XAML. You should avoid placing any code in getters and setters. This is documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) as well.

Comment: **Solution:** - use proper DataBinding. No need to do all that procedural code for anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of PresentationCell you set this.DataContext = this.
By setting DataContext to your control you are breaking the inheritance of this property and thats why setting the bindings in CreatePresentationTemplateColumn wont work.
To fix that you can remove this line and bind the controls by RelativeSource/ElementName or you can set the dataContext to the main grid in PresentationCell instead of the root level